# Android Video Player dual audio and subtitle track

Tags: java, android, audio, video

i am writing an video streaming app. I have done some research already and have found some pretty good video players. for example google's ExoPlayer and some other really good stuff on github and here on SO. But what i really need, more than just a video player, is one that be capable of open a dialog for selecting subtitle tracks and swap audio tracks on dual-audio videos (for example a two language movie, both tracks spanish and english, if i pick the english track then go to subtitle dialog and pick spanish subtitles).

VLC player and MxPlayer have this features, but i need to use an embedded player, not an third party player.

to highlight, the subtitles are already merged into the videos, they are not on a separate file, and the audio tracks are also on the same video. So is just one video file with subtitle track and audio trakcs inside.

I hope you guys can help me providing me a good self explanatory example of how can i achieve this. Please, thanks. You've always been great helping me.

Comment: This May Help You : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073927/android-video-player-mkv-video-support