# Android video player mkv video support

Tags: java, android, video, video-streaming, android-videoview

I have tried many video player libraries like [BetterVideoPlayer](https://github.com/halilozercan/BetterVideoPlayer),[GiraffeVideoPlayer](https://github.com/tcking/GiraffePlayer),[MxVideoPlayer](https://github.com/henryblue/MxVideoPlayer) but no player supports mkv format videos. I have also tried to use ijkplayer but I didn't know how to add this in my
project. I have tried it's demo project but I keeps crashing whenever I select video file from this demo.

So, my question is 
how can i play mkv videos from url in my app with video controls like (pause ,play, etc).

Comment: I don't see the question

Comment: @jle please check question...i have edited it

Comment: asking for a library is off-topic here

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I am asking for library just for simplicity, if there is any other posibility..please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ExoPlayer (https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).
According to [docs](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/supported-formats.html) it supports Matroska format.

Comment: I have also tried it but it also doesn't support mkv videos.

Answer (score 0):

Use ExoPlayer, It is one of the latest Audio/Video Players which supports multiple formats, MKV is one of the few it supports.

Comment: No, it doen't support mkv format.. i have tested it by adding mkv video link in their github sample project but it doen't work

Comment: They have not added the code for MKV in their sample app. You will have to add the same on your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the docs from Exo Player:

**Sample formats**
By default ExoPlayer uses Android’s platform decoders. Hence the supported sample formats depend on the underlying platform rather than on ExoPlayer.

So it may happen that the device does not support that mkv